# modify view before returning partial view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I am new to MVC. I have a requirement to create hidden fields on page by reading value from Request.Form. I have used below code on cshtml page.

```
@(new HtmlString("<input type='hidden' id='hdnLiveMatchItemID' value='" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["liveBlogMasterData[LiveMatchItemID]"] + "' />"))
@(new HtmlString("<input type='hidden' id='hdnMatchID' value='" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["liveBlogMasterData[MatchID]"] + "' />"))
@(new HtmlString("<input type='hidden' id='hdnMatchTagItemID' value='" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["liveBlogMasterData[MatchTagItemID]"] + "' />"))
@(new HtmlString("<input type='hidden' id='hdnLiveBlogEntryParentID' value='" + HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["liveBlogMasterData[LiveBlogEntryParentID]"] + "' />"))
```

But this looks ugly and I am sure there must be a way to do this from server side. But my server side code returns partial as below.

```
public PartialViewResult MyMethod()
{
    return PartialView("somepath/somefile.cshtml");
}
```

Can you please tell me how can I do this from server side? May be modify `PartialViewResult` before returning?

**Edit:** As per Vec**'s suggestion. I used below code but it is giving error.

```
 @model IEnumerable<LiveBlogMasterData>
            @foreach(var masterData in Model)
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => masterData)
            }
```

Comment: "code on cshtml page" *is* server side - not clear what you are asking about

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like this in your Razor template:

```
<input type='hidden' id='hdnLiveMatchItemID' value='@HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["liveBlogMasterData[LiveMatchItemID]"]' />
<input type='hidden' id='hdnMatchID' value='@HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["liveBlogMasterData[MatchID]"]' />
```

etc.

Another option is to assign the values to the ViewBag in the controller:

```
public PartialViewResult MyMethod()
{
    ViewBag.LiveMatchId = HttpContext.Request.Form["liveBlogMasterData[LiveMatchItemID]"];
}
```

and the View:

```
<input type="hidden" id="hdnLiveMatchItemID" value="@ViewBag.LiveMatchId" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send your field list to view like this

```
return PartialView("somepath/somefile.cshtml", list);
```

and than try to use in `foreach` loop, like this

```
@model ....Models.ListOfHiddenItems

    @foreach (var x in model)

    {
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.field )
    }
```

Comment: Getting error. The type argument for method HiddenFor can not be inferred from the usage.